# How to sync the data between common data service and source?

Tags: azure, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, common-data-service

I have a powerapp that is using data from an entity located in common data service.

The entity data is populated from a SQL Server.

When the powerapp updates the data, it is reflected in the common data service entity. Example - update a field.

How to sync this update to the SQL Server?

Also, when data changes on the SQL server, how to sync it with the common data service? Is there an out of the box solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally we use DES - [Data export service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/data-export-service) or Scribe replication to sync data from CDS (Dynamics CRM online) to Azure SQL server. But this is one way data flow, in other words SQL is just a Read-only mirror copy of CDS.

So you have to build the PowerApps (Canvas) to use the CDS connector for reading CDS data and you can update back, so SQL will have latest updated data intact through DES.

If you have two sources, one from CDS and one in SQL separately, then it is your responsibility to build syncing the data. Like finding the delta in SQL and update in CDS using some timely jobs or update the CDS and SQL at the same time from PowerApps.

Comment: @variable yes obviously, CRUD operation can be done.